# How to call functions defined on __proto__ object under ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I can see getCellValue function defined on **proto** object under grid instance.
I am calling the function like below:

```
grid.__proto__.getCellValue( row, col )
```

But during runtime calling getCellValue  throws an exception in console like below:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flatEntityAccess' of undefined

Is there any other way to access the functions defined on **proto** object in Ui-grid.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have the access of **proto** object. This objects is being internally inherit by the object instance. So we can make a call directly by

```
grid.getCellValue( row, col )
```